# post detail doesn't show by click in react hooks

Tags: parameters, react-hooks, react-router, use-effect, jsonplaceholder

when I click on each post item the details doesn't show on the browser(`post.js` component for showing detail of each post item). only thing that shows on the browser is white page! . these are my components:

thank you for your help.

this is my `App.js` component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import Post from "./components/Post";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
        <Route path="about" element={<About/> }></Route>
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<Post/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and `Home.js` component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts(data.slice(0, 10));
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h4 className="center">Home</h4>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div className="post card" key={post.id}>
          <div className="card-content">
            <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
              <span className="card-title">{post.title}</span>
            </Link>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And`Post.js` component for showing detail of each post item by click:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Post = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [post, setPost ]= useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
      );
      const newData = await response.json();
      setPost(newData);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{post.title}</p>
       <p>{post.body}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, and reproduce, your code throws an error when `Post` tried to render `post.title` on the initial render before the `post` state is populated. The initial `post` state value is `null` and you can't access properties of a null or undefined value.

You should conditionally render the `post` state.

Example:

```
return post ? (
  <div>
    <p>{post.title}</p>
    <p>{post.body}</p>
  </div>
) : null; // or some loading indicator, etc...
```

[image: Edit post-detail-doesnt-show-by-click-in-react-hooks]